# ImportError: No module named openai_ros_common

Tags: ros, python2.7

I am doing the tutorial from Openai_ros：http://wiki.ros.org/openai_ros/TurtleBot2%20with%20openai_ros
And when I tried launching my file: `roslaunch my_turtlebot2_training start_training.launch` , I got the following error:ImportError:

> No module named openai_ros_common

I have followed the steps strictly,where might the problem lies?

Answer (score 0):

If your tag 'python 2.7' is the Python version you use, it could be a problem.
You need to check your default Python version, and match it to python3

Comment: I have updated my python version to 3.6.9 now.Unfortunately,it still remains the error:No module named 'openai_ros.openai_ros_common'.

Comment: Could you try to reinstall?
https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/openai_ros.git/src

Comment: I have tried to reinstall and change the directory.The openai_common error has been solced.A new problemAttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'all' occurred.I just followed the demo as the wiki said.

Comment: That's good news. If openai_common error was solved, closing this question and posting new questions including the code you're running and information such as the corresponding wiki link will help with the problem solving

Comment: thank you,it seems there is only one problem here.The only problem is the missing package.I think the reason is I have not installed the turtlebot2 simulation package.I dont know where i can use git clone to get it